# Ruby on Rails go to a specific page when clicking "f.submit"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, associations, form-submit

In my Ruby on Rails application I have the following form for booking_line view:

```
<%= form_for @booking_line do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :showing_id %>
    <%= image_tag "thor_hammer.jpg",:size => "900x250" %>
    <td width="300px"> <br><%= f.label :seat_id, 'Please Select a Seat:' %>
    <br><%= f.collection_select :seat_id, free_seats, :id,:seats_available %><br>
    </td>
    <td width="300px">
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
    <br>    
    <%= render "/error_messages", :message_header => "Cannot save: ", :target => @booking_line %> 
    </td>
<% end %>
```

But as this is booking_line, what I want to happen is that when the submit button is clicked it creates a booking and a booking_line because in the booking_line table it has the attribute `booking_id` so that the association is made between the two. How can I achieve this?

Comment: have you defined the relationships? booking can have many booking_line or only one booking_line?

Comment: List your associations please (for BookingLine, Booking, and Seat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `url` in [form_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for) method..to overwrite individual conventions, such as:

```
<%= form_for(@post, url: my_custom_path) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

and then add your own logic at `my_custom` action to achieve it